# Displaying comments number in nodes title

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'd like to display comments number in node title. I wish it would look like that: */Title/ (no comments)*. What changes to node or comment module should I put to get this and what code? What if I'd like to display comments number under the nodes content where title 'Comments' is?

Thanks in advance.

[Edit] I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to edit the node template file. It is node.tpl.php (for all node types) or create node-yournodetypename.tpl.php for your node type name, copy the node.tpl.php content and edit that. There is a list of variables you can use within your template file here:

> http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php

I hope a helped a bit.

Comment: A bit ? You helped a lot! Thanks